# Python: Compare strings with 'or' operator

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, boolean, boolean-logic

In the Python3 tutorials, it is stated that "It is possible to assign the result of a comparison or other Boolean expression to a variable." The example given is:

```
>>> string1, string2, string3 = '', 'Trondheim', 'Hammer Dance'
>>> non_null = string1 or string2 or string3
>>> non_null
'Trondheim'
```

What exactly does the 'or' operator do when comparing strings? Why is 'Trondheim' chosen?

Comment: Basically, if string1 == True then non_null = string1 else if string2 == True then non_null = string2 else if string3 == True then non_null = string3 It stops at string2 because any non empty string is true in Python.

Comment: @bi0phaz3: "string" == True is false. You mean bool(string1) == True.

Comment: Python can cast implicitly for that I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When treated as boolean, an empty string will return `False` and a non empty string will return `True`.

Since Python supports short circuiting, in the expression `a or b`, `b` won't be evaluated if `a` is True.

In your example, we have `'' or 'Trondheim' or 'Hammer Dance'`.

This expression is evaluated from left to right, so the first thing being evaluated is `'' or 'Trondheim'`, or in other words `False or True`, which returns `True`. Next, Python tries to evaluate `'Trondheim' or 'Hammer Dance'` which in turn becomes `True or 'Hammer Dance'`. Because of the short circuiting mentioned earlier, because the left object is True, `'Hammer Dance'` doesn't even gets evaluated to `True`, which is why `'Trondheim'` is returned.

Answer (score 2):

Inclusive `or` selects the first non-falsy string (checking from left to right), which in this case is `'Trondheim'`

```
>>> bool('')
False
>>> bool('Trondheim')
True
```

It is sometimes preferable when performing this type of check to `strip` the string literals as a blank space is also truthy, if you intend to not select whitespaces.

```
>>> bool(' ')
True
```

Answer (score 2):

In the assignment of `non_null`, the `or` comparisons are evaluated sequentially, which translates to this :

```
if string1:
    non_null = string1
elif string2:
    non_null = string2
elif string3:
    non_null = string3
else:
    non_null = False
```

However, in your example, `string1` is an empty string, which is evaluated as `False` (you can check this by typing `if not '':print("Empty")` in your prompt).

Since `string2` is not empty, hence evaluated as `True`, it is assigned to `non_null`, hence the result.

Answer (score 1):

`or` returns the value on the left of it if that is true-ish, and the one on the right otherwise.

For strings, only `""` (the empty string) is not true-ish, and all others are.

So

```
>>> "" or "Test"
"Test"
```

and

```
>>> "One" or "Two"
"One"
```

It doesn't do a comparison at all.

Comment: Ah, I see. Short circuiting? Now I feel a little silly

Comment: Yeah, it short circuits.